# Why is IE8 adding whitespace inside a JS string concat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm writing a quick script to show and hide a ul and its contents - basically a dropdown menu.
Problem I'm having is in the code below, line 2:

```
    $('#mainMenu ul li').mouseenter(function() {
    var dropTab = 'ul.' + $(this).attr("id") + 'Dropdown';
    alert(dropTab);
    $(dropTab).slideToggle();
});
```

Works fine in FF, but in IE8 the dropTab string has whitespace between the second and third elements ie it outputs:

```
ul.someId                   Dropdown
```

when I'm looking for:

```
ul.someIdDropdown
```

Like I said, works fine in FF, but am curious as to where the whitespace is coming from, as it stops the function from performing...

Any suggestions welcome - happy to consider an alternative method

Comment: I agree with soolhsinger, anyway, can you please doublecheck that your 'id' doesn't contains whitespaces?

Comment: This may be a micro-optimization, but you should be able to use `this.id` rather than accessing the id through `jQuery.fn.attr`. See http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitespace is obviously coming from inside the `$(this).attr("id")` method. IE must not [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the id when it is returned. You may want to try changing that line to this:

```
var dropTab = 'ul.' + $.trim($(this).attr("id")) + 'Dropdown';
```

Comment: Thanks - realised the problem was stemming from malformed xslt - a couple of xsl:text tags later and that's sorted. However, the slideToggle still won't cooperate. Meh.